# Acrobat Javascript - Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, if-statement, checkbox, acrobat

I'm needing help creating a document-level javascript in Acrobat DC for checkboxes.  Example: if Checkbox 1 or Checkbox 2 are selected, then Checkbox 3 will be visible.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function MainShop()
{

var c1 = getField("MS 12 CHECK").value;
var c2 = getField("MS 13 CHECK").value;
var c3 = getField("MS CHECK");

if(event.target===c1 || event.target===c2){
c3.display.visible;
c3.display.hidden;
}

}
```

I have tried the following code in the Mouse Up Event for each of Checkbox 1 and Checkbox 2.  This code partially works.  If I were to select both 1 and/or 2, then checkbox 3 appears.  If I deselect 1, then checkbox 3 disappears and it needs to stay visible since 2 is still selected.

```js
this.getField("MB CHECK").display = event.target.value=="Off" ? display.hidden : display.visible;
```

This is why I think I need code at the Document-Level Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

First you need to detect when the user changes the checkbox (selects or deselects them). On that function, you need to perform the check to see if the first or second checkbox is selected, and if so, you display the third checkbox.

```js
const getField = document.getElementById.bind(document);
const fields = ["MS 12 CHECK", "MS 13 CHECK", "MS CHECK"];
const displayCheck = _ => {
  const oneOrTwoChecked = getField(fields[0]).firstChild.checked || getField(fields[1]).firstChild.checked;
  getField(fields[2]).style.display = oneOrTwoChecked ? "inline" : "none";
}
fields.forEach(x => getField(x).addEventListener("change", displayCheck));
```

```html
<label id="MS 12 CHECK"><input type="checkbox"/> MS 12 CHECK</label>
<label id="MS 13 CHECK"><input type="checkbox"/> MS 13 CHECK</label>
<label id="MS CHECK" style="display: none;"><input type="checkbox"/> MS CHECK</label>
```

Comment: I think this is a little extensive for what I'm looking for.  This code works if placed into one of the Checkbox properties.  The problem is that it's only specific to that one checkbox and not checking for others.  this.getField("MB CHECK").display = event.target.value=="Off" ? display.hidden : display.visible;

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of  what is your current approach. The javascript alone isn't enough to fully understand what you mean.

Comment: I added to my original post above.  Hope this explains things a little better.